# httplib.HTTPSConnection ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579) given right certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, certificate, x509certificate

Calling httplib.HTTPSConnection with valid certificate files (cert_file, key_file) makes this error, but when I call httplib.HTTPSConnection with SSLContext parameter than verification is ok.

What could be the problem/difference?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013'
>>> h = httplib.HTTPSConnection('valid.host.name', 1111, 'server.pem', 
'server.pem')
>>> h.connect()
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1237, in connect
    server_hostname=sni_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 350, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 612, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 834, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed 
(_ssl.c:579)
>>>
>>> PROTOCOL = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23
>>> context = ssl.SSLContext(PROTOCOL)
>>> context.load_default_certs()
>>> clientCert = 'server.pem'
>>> clientKey = 'server.pem'
>>> context.load_cert_chain(clientCert, clientKey)
>>> h = httplib.HTTPSConnection('valid.host.name', 1111, context=context)
>>> h.connect()
>>>
```

Looking into the ssl.py and httplib.py in the depth HTTPSConnection class with key_file, cert_file parameters calls the same methods (load_default_certs, load_cert_chain) as above.

```
server.pem is a self-signed x509 certificate.
```